# Getting default value of property using php reflection

Tags: php, reflection

I'm looking for a way to access the default value assignment for a property without instantiating the class.

E.g.

```
class Foo {
   private $bar = 'bar';
}

$reflClass = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$reflProp = $reflClass->getProperty('bar');
```

Now what? If I use `$reflProp->getValue()` (without an object argument) it will fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`getDefaultProperties()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdefaultproperties.php):

```
var_dump($reflClass->getDefaultProperties());
```

Comment: +1 Very, very nice. I can hear the reflection API screaming to be documented.